# Are the words “how” and “howl” pronounced the same?

Tags: pronunciation

I can see some differences when I listen to someone saying “Howl“ with the purpose of showing how it is pronounced. But I want to know if in a native would be able to tell which word someone is saying without a context in a normal conversation. For example:
Person A: “What is your dog's name?“
Person B: “His name is Howl“
Would Person A know that Person B said “Howl“?
In a conversation I would say “howl“ with a silence “L“. I can pronounce the “L“ but it sounds unnatural. Maybe I just need to improve my pronunciation of the word?

Comment: I have never heard *howl* pronounced with a silent *L*. But assuming I did, context has to determine what is meant. If context can't, then it's ambiguous.

Comment: Pronounce it anyway you like, but the "proper" pronunciation has an "L" sound.

Comment: I'll add that "howl" is really a syllable and a half, with a sort of "wool" sound on the end.  Some people pronounce this more distinctly than others.

Comment: @Hotlicks do you say "These people were not _ha-wool-ling_ barbarians, as you may have thought..." Or "_how-ling_"? I say it the second way. I was born in central Appalachia, but have British uncles and aunts on one side.

Comment: @Conrado - Basically, you pronounce "howl" as "howling", only you drop the "ing".  But the "l" is still trying to be a separate syllable (only not really managing to).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore., Done.